# ContainerRequestFilter method not being called on WAS liberty

Tags: rest, filter, websphere-liberty

I have filter class on my WAS Liberty server:

```
// TestRequestFilter.java
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Secured
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class TestRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DemoRESTRequestFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestCtx) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("FILTER-REQUEST");
    }
}
```

And custom annotation:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Secured {

}
```

And a rest call:

```
@GET
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Secured
    public Response login(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization) {
        return Response.ok("OK").build();
    }
```

Server.xml:

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

How to make Filter work on a WAS ?

Comment: What's your server config (server.xml)? What features in particular?

Comment: I have added my server.xml into a question

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `TestRequestFilter`:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons()
    {
        Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
        singletons.add(new TestRequestFilter());
        // register others, if any
        return singletons;
    }
}
```